# offsetWidth not calculated properly when text has a special character

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, width

i am trying to find the text width for my scenario.
here is my code(Simple Example)

```
var text = "Country <textinbrackets> and some following text";
var textObj = document.createElement('text');
$(textObj).attr({ 'id': 'measureTex'});
document.body.appendChild(textObj); 
textObj.innerHTML = text;
alert("Text Width:" + textObj.offsetWidth + " " + "Text Height:" + textObj.offsetHeight);
```

when i use the tag in my text(**<>**) it was not considered () so i can't able to find the exact width of the text.
Actual width of the text is 323 but it returned as 212..
how to find the exact width..

Sample Link :http://jsfiddle.net/W4Km8/7047/

how to solve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `<textinbrackets>` has been rendered as an html element. If you inspect the text you'll see the `<textinbrackets>` as an html element.

just replace "<" with

```
&lt;
```

and ">" with

```
&gt;
```

So, your text looks like

```
var text = "Country &lt;textinbrackets&gt; and some following text";
```

If you don't want to change the text then use this.

```
textObj.innerText = text;
```

Comment: yes correct because of <>. but with out changing that text there is any possible to get exact width